# How do I Combine two equal sized vectors element wise in MatLab?

Tags: matlab, vector

I have two vectors:

```
a = [1 3 5 7 9];
b = [2 4 6 8 10];
```

That I need to combine together element wise.  Meaning that I need the first element of vector a, then the first element of vector b, second of a, second of b, and so forth until I get the following:

```
combined = [1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10]
```

How do I do this within MatLab?

#### Edit

I ran a test of the top three answers (Josh, Marc, & Kronos) and compared the time it took to run them.  I ran each 100 times after doing a 10 iteration warmup.  The vectors created were exactly the same size in length (16e+6) and were random values ranging from 1 to 100:

```
Test Results
Test:           Total Time (100 runs):      Avg Time Per Exec:
Josh B          21.3687                     0.2137
Marc C          21.4273                     0.2143
Kronos          31.1897                     0.3119
```

It appears that both Josh's and Marc's solutions are similar in execution time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
a = [1 3 5 7 9];
b = [2 4 6 8 10];
temp = [a; b];
combined = temp(:)';
```

Comment: You should just use `[a,b]` instead of `[a;b]` followed by the transpose.

Comment: and it seems this won't work if `a` and `b` don't have exactly the same size.

Comment: If you mean use `[a b]` instead of `[a; b]` and then drop the transpose on `temp(:)`, then that doesn't look right to me.

Comment: @fpe The problem definition makes no sense unless they have exactly the same size, except for maybe a size difference of +/- 1

Comment: I'm accepting yours as it's a bit easier to read and has the same execution time as @Marc's.

Answer (score 3):

This can be done by the following:

```
a = [1 3 5 7 9];
b = [2 4 6 8 10];
combinedSize = size(a, 2) * 2;

combined(1:2:combinedSize) = a;
combined(2:2:combinedSize) = b;
```

This is obviously assuming that your vectors are exactly the same size.  If by chance you want to merge two vectors that are not the same size then you can do the following:

```
combinedSize = max(size(a, 2), size(b, 2)) * 2;
combined = NaN(1,combinedSize);
combined(1:2:size(a,2)*2) = a;
combined(2:2:size(b,2)*2) = b;
```

This will place a `NaN` for the remaining elements of the smaller vector.  For example, given the following sample vectors:

```
a = [1 3 5 7 9 11];
b = [2 4 6 8];
```

will result in the combined vector:

```
combined =

     1     2     3     4     5     6     7     8     9   NaN    11   NaN
```

Comment: Didn't you ask the question?

Comment: Despite being slower, I think this is probably the best solution, since it is the clearest.

Comment: @RoneyMichael I did but after asking the question it turned into a 'rubber ducky' programming moment. I figured out the solution after asking the question and wanted to share my findings.

Comment: Perhaps you can make it work for arbitrary pairs by initializing to zero or NaN and giving it the size of the largest array

Answer (score 1):

Place the vectors below eachother in a matrix and use `reshape`. For example:

```
>> A=[1 2 3]

A =

     1     2     3

>> B=[4 5 6]

B =

     4     5     6

>> C=reshape([A;B],1,size(A,2)+size(B,2))

C =

     1     4     2     5     3     6
```

It's straightforward to generalize to more than 2 vectors.

Comment: Interesting, will this work for vectors that aren't the same size?

Comment: No, you will not be able to concatenate them into a matrix. Maybe you can get it to work with some `repmat` magic, though ...

Comment: I don't need to in this case, but was curious in case someone else coming along might want to know.

Comment: @KronoS If the vectors weren't the same length, then what you asked for wouldn't make sense.

Answer (score 0):

You can also give a try to looping, for example:

```
a=[1 2 3 4 5];
b=[11 12 13 14 15];

for i = 1:N

{

if (i%2==0)
{ c[i] = b[i]; }
else
{ c[i] = a[i]; }
```

This shall work!

Comment: The problem with this is that I have vector that can be up to 16 mil+ long. Dealing with loops then take forever and matlab is optimized for dealing with whole matrices or vectors.

Answer (score 0):

All the answers above only work if the two vectors have the same number of elements. The following will work even if they have different number of elements:

```
>> 
A = [1 3 5];
B = [2 4 6 7 8];
C = [1 3 5 7 8];
D = [2 4 6];

AB = nan(1,2*max(numel(A),numel(B)));
CD = nan(1,2*max(numel(C),numel(D)));

AB(2*(1:length(A))) = A;
AB(1+2*(1:length(B))) = B;
CD(2*(1:length(C))) = C;
CD(1+2*(1:length(D))) = D;
>> 
AB = AB(~isnan(AB))
CD = CD(~isnan(CD))
```

The result would be:

```
AB =

     1     2     3     4     5     6     7     8


CD =

     1     2     3     4     5     6     7     8
```

Comment: This makes an assumption about how he/she wants to treat this case (i.e. that after one vector runs out of elements, the result should just be built by taking elements in order from the other).

Comment: @JoshuaBarr: Wouldn't that be the intuitive way? Besides, this will work when the number of elements are equal as well.

Comment: This solution makes an assumption, that's all I'm saying. I usually prefer code that fails fast and hard when an unexpected condition arises.